# Android_apk "Parsing the package" error

Tags: android, parsing

Firstly, I'd like to apologize if it's a repost. I'm a newbie to Android app development. I've searched for the same error here but some of the questions were unanswered and others weren't understandable for a newbie like me. So, sorry guys.

**So, I have developed an app in android with a minimum API version being 2.2
The app works fine if I transfer it on a local device using USB but it gives the error "Parsing the package" if someone tries to download it via email. The downloading stops midway and the phone displays the error, but if the app gets downloaded to a 100%, it works.**
The "install from unknown sources" option has been checked on every device I use to install the app.

If needed, I can provide you with further details about the app.

-Thanks

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is to check your internet connectivity.. You claimed that `The downloading stops midway and the phone displays the error`.. So that's the issue.. The phone should download the whole application to be able to install it. How is the phone supposed to install an application when it's half downloaded and corrupted?

Comment: The internet connectivity is fine.

Answer (score 0):

following cases may cause this problem :

**1.** API **greater than `minSdkVersion`** (defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`) i.e. Package is compiled on higher API level but using on lower API

**2.** code **Name of the package is changed** after signing: Use the exact name as the signed package is (instead of renaming the name in Manifest)

**3.**  **executed from SD-card** than execute from phones memory.

Comment: 1. The minimum sdk is 8 and the maximum is 17. So that app should run fine between Froyo to Jelly Bean. The package was complied on the Android 2.2 and is being used on higher APIs. 
2. The code name of the package is not changed. It works if transfered to a device using USB.

Comment: @KartikArora does it also happens to other applications ? or for this application only ?